# Can I offset the map frame in the composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a map frame in a layout in which the map fills the frame. If I check the frame property checkbox, there is no whitespace between the contents and the frame. Is there a way to offset the frame? I know I can draw a rectangle around the frame and center the objects, but it's hard to get the aspect ratios identical.
qgis 2.01 64 bit
Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to control the size and position of the map item in the item properties.
There is no "padding" property for map items. Instead, I suggest to position the map manually on the page. An alternative might be to add a wide white frame (also in the map item properties).

You can draw a rectangle around the map at some distance to get the additional hairline black border. Using manual positioning, it shouldn't be too hard to get it right.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make my objective sufficiently clear. I'd like my map item to have some white space around it and then a hairline black border. Since the map item contents bleed right to the edge of the map item, there is no whitespace when the frame is selected.

Comment: @Llaves Ok, now it's clear what you want to achieve. The only problem is that that's not possible directly. But you can draw a rectangle around the map at some distance to get the additional hairline black border. Using manual positioning, it shouldn't be too hard to get it right.